# Unable to access the history from the props in a component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have one base component named(EnterSystem) on which I am calling (Login) and (Register) component. I am passing props from Enter System to Login and Register by using `{...this.props}` in Login component. After submitting the data and validating it with database, I am redirecting it to some other component(ListEnterprises) using `this.props.history.push("/enterprises")`. But I need this history in the (ListEnterprise) component to redirect it futher to some other component. But `this.props` is undefined. Can any body please help?

**EnterSystem**

```
class EnterSystem extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLogginActive: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Add .right by default
        this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
    }

    changeState() {
        const { isLogginActive } = this.state;

        if (isLogginActive) {
            this.rightSide.classList.remove("right");
            this.rightSide.classList.add("left");
        } else {
            this.rightSide.classList.remove("left");
            this.rightSide.classList.add("right");
        }
        this.setState(prevState => ({ isLogginActive: !prevState.isLogginActive }));
    }

    render() {
        const { isLogginActive } = this.state;
        const current = isLogginActive ? "Register" : "Login";
        const currentActive = isLogginActive ? "login" : "register";
        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationComponent />
                <div className="Enter">
                    <div className="login">
                        <div className="container" ref={ref => (this.container = ref)} >
                            {isLogginActive && (
                                <Login {...this.props} containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
                            )}
                            {!isLogginActive && (
                                <Register {...this.props} containerRef={ref => (this.current = ref)} />
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <RightSide current={current} currentActive={currentActive} containerRef={ref => (this.rightSide = ref)} onClick={this.changeState.bind(this)} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <FooterComponent />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const RightSide = props => {
    return (
        <div className="right-side" ref={props.containerRef} onClick={props.onClick}>
            <div className="inner-container">
                <div className="text">{props.current}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EnterSystem;
```

**Login**

```
export class Login extends Component {

    emptyCredential = {
        username: "",
        password: "",
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            hasLoginFailed: false,
            showSuccessMessage: false,
            credential: this.emptyCredential
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.loginClicked = this.loginClicked.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;

        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        let updatedCredential = { ...this.state.credential };
        updatedCredential[name] = value;
        this.setState({ credential: updatedCredential });
        console.log(updatedCredential);
    }

    loginClicked(event) {
        const payload = this.state.credential;
        console.log("Printing Payload ");
        console.log(payload);
        console.log(payload.username);
        console.log(payload.password)
        AuthenticationService.executeJwtAuthenticationService(payload)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLoginForJwt(payload.username, response.data.id_token);
                this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasLoginFailed: false, showSuccessMessage: true });
                this.props.history.push("/enterprises");
                // // <Redirect to={{
                // //     pathname: '/enterprises'
                // // }}
                // // />
                // <ListEnterprises name="history" historyId="this.props"  />
                // this.props.history.push({ pathname: "/enterprises" });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasLoginFailed: true, showSuccessMessage: false });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
                <div className="header">Login</div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="image">
                        <img src={LoginImg} />
                    </div>
                    {this.state.hasLoginFailed && <div className="alert alert-warning">Invalid Credentials</div>}
                    {this.state.showSuccessMessage && <div>Login Sucessful</div>}
                    <div className="form">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="username" for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.loginClicked}>Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**ListEnterprises**

```
class ListEnterprises extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            enterprises: [],
            message: null,
            showFormMessage: false,
        }
        //Any method in a react component should be bound to this
        this.refreshEnterprises = this.refreshEnterprises.bind(this);
    }

    // After all the elements of the page is rendered correctly, this method is called.
    // After the markup is set on the page, this technique called by React itself to either fetch the data from An External API or perform some unique operations which need the JSX.API
    // componentDidMount() method is the perfect place, where we can call the setState() method to change the state of our application and render() the updated data loaded JSX. For example, we are going to fetch any data from an API then API call should be placed in this lifecycle method,
    // and then we get the response, we can call the setState() method and render the element with updated data.
    //React defines a component lifecycle. componentDidMount will be called as soon as the component is mounted. We are calling refreshCourses as soon as a component is mounted.
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshEnterprises();
    }

    _showMessage = (bool) => {
        this.setState({
            showFormMessage: bool
        });
    }

    refreshEnterprises() {
        EnterpriseService.retrieveAllEnterprises()
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.setState({ enterprises: response.data, isLoading: false });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Enterprises");

        if (this.state.isLoading)
            return (<div>Loading...</div>);

        return (
            <div>
                <NavigationComponent /><br /><br />
                <h3 align="center">Here are all your Enterprises</h3><br />
                {this.state.message && <div class="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>}
                <Container>
                    <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Enterprise</th>
                                <th>Industry</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Update</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.enterprises.map(
                                    enterprise =>
                                        <tr key={enterprise.id}>
                                            <td>{enterprise.enterpriseName}</td>
                                            <td>{enterprise.industry}</td>
                                            <td>{enterprise.description}</td>
                                            <td><button className="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>
                                            <td><button className="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Container>{" "}{" "}{" "}

                <div className="container">
                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, true)}>Add Enterprise</Button>{' '}
                    <Button color="secondary" size="lg" onClick={this._showMessage.bind(null, false)}>Hide</Button>{' '}
                    {this.state.showFormMessage && (<AddEnterprise {...this.props} />)}
                </div>
                <FooterComponent />
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default ListEnterprises;
```

**App.js(Routing is defined here)**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {}
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
          <Route path="/enter" exact={true} component={EnterSystem} />
          <Route path="/enterprises"><ListEnterprises /></Route>
          // {/* <Route path='/categories' exact={true} component={Category} /> */}
          {/* <Route path='/expenses' exact={true} component={Expenses} /> */}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Need to send props from ListEnterprises to AddEnterprise.**

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you think your problem is solved, please considere [marking an answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). "Accepting an answer is important as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question, informs others that your issue is resolved, and pins the answer to the top so others reading your question read that answer first.". have a great day .

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I accepted the the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `<ListEnterprises />` is loaded as a [Route component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component), `history` will automatically be provided in props and can be accessed using `this.props.history`.

```
<Route path="/enterprises" component={ListEnterprises} />
```

Comment: Thanks...It works fine. Now I am able to access this.props.history. Payload is adding into the database,but it is not redirecting to "ListEnterprises". Actually, nothing is happening. But, when I refresh the ListEnterprise component, I am seeing the updated data.

Comment: Glad you now have access to history. Sounds like you have some issues handling your request's answer, probably perfect issue for an other question .

Comment: @gibran: Did you missclick and accept my answer, it should be the one of sebastiam, right ?

Comment: Any idea how to redirect to a same component from a component?

Ex:- Redirect to the component A from component A(with update data after DB operation)

Answer (score 0):

Add `withRouter` HOC (Higher Order Component) to your component and use it like below:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class ListEnterprises extends Component {/* Your component code goes here */}

export default withRouter(ListEnterprises);
```